# Accessing Android 5.1 internal API's

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I'm trying to access the hidden API's for Android 5.1 (22), but I'm having difficulties getting the project to compile. The steps I've taken:

1. Pulled boot.oat from a device running 5.1
2. Ran oat2dex to get the dex and odex folders
3. Ran dex2jar on framework.dex and framework-classes2.dex, got both working like a charm [after modifying classes2.dex so dex2jar would run](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar/issues/10)
4. Merged the two resulting folders, copied their content
5. In /platforms/android-22, unzipped android.jar, copied over the files from previous step, zipped it back up
6. Android Studio invalidate cache and restart
7. Clean project

Now I'm getting an app:processDebugResources error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Even after running with --stacktrace and --debug, the error isn't obvious sadly. I've read the whole of the internet at this point, trying to find out what the issue could be, but no luck. My gradle file is like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "<ID>"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 0
        versionName "0.3"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false /*Include these three statements to build app quickly (at least faster than     before :p) */
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"  // To avoid GC Limit Exception
        jumboMode = true  // To avoid GC Limit Exception
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.5.87'

    compile 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.3.2'
    apt 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.3.2'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

I've tried creating a new project and compiling, again same error, so I'm fairly sure it's not the setup/dependencies. I'm using gradle build 1.2.3, I've tried different versions, same error.

At this point I really don't know what else to try - any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You probably really want to use `Reflection` to access the APIs.  Or build your own sdk that exposes the required APIs.  CyanogenMod and AOKP take this approach to their development.

Pitfalls:
Reflection is slow so use with caution.

Building your own sdk could have other dangers like breaking compatibility with real world devices.  Also keep in mind OEMs are free to modify the hidden APIs to meet their requirements, so the hidden APIs may not exist on all devices.  CyanogenMod can do this because they are running the apps on their firmware so they know the APIs exist.